# Disadvantage of for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

What are the actual disadvantages of for loop? No, I mean seriously. There must be something right. There are while and do while loops, both effective, yet we have a for loop. There must be some disadvantage in for loop due to which while and do while were developed, right?

Comment: There are no disadvantages, if one better shows your intent than the other, use it.

Comment: All the loop constructs are completely equivalent. You might as well have asked for disadvantages of while loops!

Comment: I have lots of similar, but slightly different screwdrivers in my toolbox.  I always choose the most appropriate one for the job at hand.

Comment: @paddy I agree, you always have to be resourceful and flexible. If you look at your toolbox and there is only *One screwdriver to screw them all* then you probably need to expand your tools collection.

Answer (score 3):

No, `while` loops are the basic structure for making loops, based on conditional gotos or assembly jumps if you will. However, because the following code was being written all the time to go through arrays:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < N)
{
    //do something, probably access an array
    i++;
}
```

They created a cleaner, more readable, way to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

This is an example of what is called [Syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Because there is no *inherent* reason for these kind of things to exist a famous quote of Alan Perlis goes "syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon".

That being said, you always have to strive for more readable codes, so go for it.

Comment: Furthermore, there is also a trivial way to transform between while loops and do-while loops, rendering all 3 loop constructs completely equivalent. `do { <BODY> } while (cond);` is completely equivalent to `{ <BODY> } while(cond) { <BODY> }`.

Comment: The `for` loop is also in FORTRAN, which predates C++ and C.

Comment: this is going to be a good slap to my friend. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No disvantages at all. I think that Go language did away with while(), it just has for().

Answer (score 0):

Even though while(cond){...} and for(; cond; ){...} are equivalent. However, writing a for loop in this way without a counter and incremental expression is weird. To make your code easier and readable, you should use the for-loop in its original and natural format. i.e., for (counter; cond; expr). If you can iterate your loop's body according to the evaluation of a particular expression, then you should stick with a while loop.

Answer (score -1):

The disadvantage may be that with the only `for` loop the "`while(cond) { /* do something*/ }`" were been invalid code... :-)

Comment: Actually, with a for loop you can. "while(cond) { /* do something*/ }" is the equivalent of "for(;cond;) { /* do something*/ }". Try it.